# Check which cmake preset was used previously

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

#### Question:

I do have several presets for my project. Now, is there a way after doing

```
cmake -B build --preset my_preset
```

to check which preset I was using?

#### Notes:

Or maybe there is a way to extract the used variables and then backtrack the preset? With `--list-presets` combined with `-N` a little script could check which preset was used. But no clue here really.